# sort semicolon separated values per row in a column

Tags: oracle11g

I want to sort semicolon separated values per row in a column. Eg.

```
Input:          
abc;pqr;def;mno            
xyz;pqr;abc            
abc           
xyz;jkl

Output:          
abc;def;mno;pqr             
abc;pqr;xyz           
abc        
jkl;xyz
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this. Breaking it down:

First we need to break up the strings into their component tokens, and then reassemble them, using `LISTAGG()`, while ordering them alphabetically.

There are many ways to break up a symbol-separated string. Here I demonstrate the use of a hierarchical query. It requires that the input strings be uniquely distinguished from each other. Since the exact same semicolon-separated string may appear more than once, and since there is no info from the OP about any other unique column in the table, I create a unique identifier (using `ROW_NUMBER()`) in the most deeply nested subquery. Then I run the hierarchical query to break up the inputs and then reassemble them in the outermost `SELECT`.

```
with
     test_data as (
       select 'abc;pqr;def;mno' as str from dual union all
       select 'xyz;pqr;abc'            from dual union all        
       select 'abc'                    from dual union all
       select 'xyz;jkl'                from dual
     )
-- End of test data (not part of the solution!)
-- SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE.
select str,
       listagg(token, ';') within group (order by token) as sorted_str
from   (
         select rn, str, 
                regexp_substr(str, '([^;]*)(;|$)', 1, level, null, 1) as token
         from   (
                  select str, row_number() over (order by null) as rn
                  from   test_data
                )
         connect by level <= length(str) - length(replace(str, ';')) + 1
                and prior rn = rn
                and prior sys_guid() is not null
       )
group by rn, str
;

STR             SORTED_STR
--------------- ---------------
abc;pqr;def;mno abc;def;mno;pqr
xyz;pqr;abc     abc;pqr;xyz
abc             abc
xyz;jkl         jkl;xyz

4 rows selected.
```